# Meaning of $x_i$ in a vector $\mathbf x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

That is the meaning of $x_i\in\mathbb R$ in the following? I mean, what is the index $i$?

> A vector is 
>   $$\mathbf x=(x_1,\dots, x_n), \quad x_i\in\mathbb R
> $$

Comment: The index $i$ is running from 1 to $n$ to say each $x_i$ is a real number. I mean, that $x_1$ is a real number, $x_2$ is a real number,... and that $x_n$ is a real number. To avoid this you shortly say that each $x_i$ is a real number.

Comment: Sometimes, people add the set of the index $i$: $$ \mathbf x = (x_1,\dots,x_n), \quad x_i\in \mathbb R, \quad \forall i\in\{1,2,\dots, n\}.$$

Comment: Hi @Dog_69 I have also seen $$\mathbf x = (x_1,\dots,x_n), \quad x_i\in \mathbb R, \quad i=1,2,\dots, n$$ But I guess the notation $\forall i\in\{1,2,\dots, n\}$ is more correct, because $i$ is a set?

Comment: Hummm... Well,  now I'm studying some Set theory,  and there everything is a set.  But,  in "real life",  considering $i$ as a set... I don't think it might be a good idea. Anyway,  I hope other clever members can give you a more satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 0):

The index is just used to specify that $x_{i} \in \mathbb{R}$,  where $1 \leq i \leq n$. In other words, if $n$ was 3, then $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ would all be real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It means that $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$, i.e. $x_1 \in \mathbb{R}, x_2 \in \mathbb{R},$ etc.

Because the range of $i$ is obvious from writing $x$ right in front, it was left out.

Answer (score 0):

The $i$ stands in for “any of the indices.” It’s really just a shorthand. The full expression should be something like $$\bigcup_{i=1}^n\{i\}\subset\Bbb R$$

The origin is somewhere in “index notation” of general relativity, wherein statements rely almost entirely on indices and physicists drop summation symbols by convention. For example,

$${\bf w}\cdot{\bf z} = \sum_{i}w_iz_i = w_iz_i$$

where ${\bf w} = \pmatrix{w_1 & \cdots & w_n}^{\sf T}$ and ${\bf z} = \pmatrix{z_1 & \cdots & z_n}^{\sf T}$.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, the entries in a vector may be thought of as coordinates in a system.  They are part of a location, and all the coordinates together constitute the direction of the vector (location in a system).

Each coordinate, $x_i$, represents some important aspect of the system.